# Java buffered stream slow in comparison to http POST

Tags: java, php, http, stream

I have written a server in Java, and a server in php.

When uploading a 5-8KB file to the java server, using `ObjectOutputStream` chained with `BufferedOutputStream` it uploads in ~2-3 seconds.

A 1.38MB file uploads in ~7 seconds.

When uploading a 5-8KB file to the php server via http POST, it takes less than 1 second.

A 1.38MB file uploads in ~2 seconds.

The question is, is this normal? Are java streams really that much slower than http methods or am I missing something/doing something wrong?

My code is below.

Client:

```
 MessageUploadFile msgUF = new MessageUploadFile(_myPhoneNumber, destNumber, extension, (int)file.length());                                     

 try {

        genConnection.sendMessage(msgUF);   
        Socket s = genConnection.getSocket();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)file.length()];   
        bis.read(buffer);                            
        OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
        bos.write(buffer);
        bos.flush();

        bis.close();                            
     }
```

`genConnection` is of type `ConnectionToServer`:

```
public class ConnectionToServer {

    private Socket _socketToServer;
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;


    public ConnectionToServer(Socket socketToServer) throws IOException {

        _socketToServer = socketToServer;
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(_socketToServer.getOutputStream()));
        sendMessage(new MessageStartConnection(""));
        in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(_socketToServer.getInputStream()));

    }

    public void sendMessage(MessageToServer msg) throws IOException {

        out.writeObject(msg);
        out.flush();

    }

    public MessageToClient getMessage() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

        return (MessageToClient) in.readObject();
    }

    public void closeConnection() throws IOException {

        _socketToServer.close();
    }

    public void resetOutputStream() throws IOException {

        out.reset();
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return _socketToServer;
    }

}
```

Server Code:

```
    Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
    String path = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
    File newFile = new File(path+"\\uploads\\"+_destPhone+"\\"+_srcPhone+"."+_extension);
    newFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    newFile.createNewFile();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    Socket s = clientConnection.getSocket();
    InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);      
    byte[] buffer = new byte[_fileSize];
    bis.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);
    bos.write(buffer);
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
```

clientConnection is of type ConnectionToClient:

```
public class ConnectionToClient {

private Socket _clientSocket;
private ObjectOutputStream _out;
private ObjectInputStream _in;

public ConnectionToClient(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {

    _clientSocket = clientSocket;
    _out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(_clientSocket.getOutputStream()));       
    _in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(_clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    writeToClient(new MessageStartConnectionRes());

}

public void writeToClient(MessageToClient msg) throws IOException {

    _out.writeObject(msg);
    _out.flush();

}

public MessageToServer getClientMessage() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

    return (MessageToServer) _in.readObject();
}

public void closeSocket() throws IOException {

    _clientSocket.close();

}
```

}

Comment: I don't see ObjectOutputStream in your code

Comment: Sorry I encapsulated it in a class named ConnectionToServer. Added it now. Thanks.

Comment: I think more than file upload it must be taking more time in serialization and deserialization of the object. Have you tried a simple file upload without objectoutputstream? Also what is in getClientMessage() method?

Comment: Sorry, another encapsulated class ConnectionToClient. Added it. Please be forgivable, first time posting to stackoverflow :)

So what do you mean by simple file upload? Can you give me a reference to such an upload?

Comment: What kind of file are you trying to transfer?

Comment: Mostly images, audio and video files. So is there a better way to upload without suffering the overhead of serialization and de-serialization? Using DataOutputStream instead maybe? or something similar?

Comment: Okay so I listened to your advice, and now I am directly writing the bytes of the file, without sending an object. So no need for Serialization. This works much faster. Thanks.

But now it seems I am in a different pickle. When writing objects I could complete the upload and then keep listening to the input stream on the server's end. Now it seems I must close the socket, otherwise the file is not written...

Comment: I doubt you have to close the socket, just closing the stream should do. Could you please update your code, may be just the bit where you are facing the error(only the write part)

Comment: The thing is I don't want to close the stream, because it is a stream I want to continue writing and receiving with later on. My latest code for some reason works when I run on debug, but transfers only a part of the file and then throws java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 91 on the next InputStream.read() when I run regularly. Updated the code. Thanks!